# Plotting in logarithm scale (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a set of data, which should be plotted in a loglog scale. x-values are always positive, but y-values are positive and negative. So, `loglog` command will just omit negative y-values. But I want to plot them: I want to have y-axis in logarithmic scale, but with negative values, as well as positive values.

Basically, if we have set of data `(x,y)`,
I want to plot: `(log(x),log(y))`, if `y>0`, and `(log(x),-log(-y))`, if `y<0`. I tried to to use these formula, and then simple `plot` function, but with this approach axes are not in logarithmic scale. Once again, I want both axes to be in logarithmic scale.

Thanks

Edit: to clarify, I want the result to be exactly as `plot(x,y)`, but both y-axis and x-axis to be in logarithmic scale

Comment: Can you add sample `x` and `y` values to the question? Its becoming confusing what you actually want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few functions for plotting logarithmic plots: along y, along x or both:
[`semilogy`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html), [`semilogx`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html), [`loglog`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html). You'll need the `loglog` one:

```
ypos = y(y>0); % Gets positive values
xpos = x(y>0); % Get corresponding x values
yneg = y(y<0); % Gets negative values
xneg = x(y<0); % Get corresponding x values
figure;
loglog(xpos,ypos)
hold on
loglog(xneg,-yneg, 'r')
```

This basically creates two plots in the same figure, one with the positive and one with the negative `y` values. In short:

```
figure;
loglog(x(y>0),y(y>0))
hold on
loglog(x(y<0),-y(y<0),'r')
```

Since the logarithm is by definition strict positive, you cannot create a negative scale. What you can do is give the illusion you have one by setting

```
set(gca, 'xdir','reverse')
```

This does mean you'd need two separate plots though, to prevent the x-axis from the positive numbers running backwards as well.

Comment: Thanks for the respond! But this is not what I want. I tried your code on the set: `x=[0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.1,1]`, `y=[0.00001,-0.0001,0.001,-0.1,1]`. The y-axis has only positive values, so you code basically treats negative values of `y` as positive. I want y-axis to have both negative and positive values.

Comment: That's impossible. The logarithm is per definition strict positive. What I suggest it plotting the negative y-values in a different colour and mention that in your figure caption.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I thought about it as well. I asked it, because may be someone knows the better solution

Comment: added a final attempt to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I accpeted the answer. Do you know the tools, which can be used to develop my own plotter?

Comment: Thanks for the accept, glad I could do my part. I do not know much about plotting, but try the Imaging Toolbox

Comment: @MikhailGenkin Ask another question, "your own plotter" is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

As [Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723311/1552737) pointed out you can use [`loglog()`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html) to plot data on a log-log scale. However, going back to the question

> I want to plot: (log(x),log(y)), if y>0, and (log(x),-log(-y)), if y<0. I tried to to use these formula, and then simple plot function, but with this approach axes are not in logarithmic scale.

You could take this approach and then set the axes to use a log-log scale with `set(gca, 'XScale', 'log')` and `set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')` for the **x** and **y** axes respectively.

Comment: That is almost what I want! But after I'm doing `set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')`, it starts to omit negative values.

Comment: Yes, because, as I pointed out, the logarithm is not defined for negative values and you cannot plot that which is not defined.